# Не запускается Apache NIFI в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache-nifi

Запускаю NiFi на Ubuntu

```
./nifi.sh start
```

Вывод в консоли

```
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
NiFi home: /home/user/nifi-1.15.0

Bootstrap Config File: /home/user/nifi-1.15.0/conf/bootstrap.conf
```

Перехожу на http://localhost:8080/nifi, но пишет,что Не удается получить доступ к сайту.

Вывод статуса

```
user@user-System-Product-Name:~/nifi-1.15.0/bin$ ./nifi.sh status

Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
NiFi home: /home/user/nifi-1.15.0

Bootstrap Config File: /home/user/nifi-1.15.0/conf/bootstrap.conf

2021-12-14 09:29:09,686 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is 
currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 45971, PID=53923
```

Лог из nifi-app.log

```
2021-12-14 10:15:57,028 INFO [main] 
o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started 
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4ced17f3{nifi-api,/nifi- 
api,file:///home/user/nifi-1.15.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-api- 
1.15.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-server- 
nar-1.15.0.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web- 
api-1.15.0.war}
2021-12-14 10:15:57,268 INFO [main] 
o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=81ms
2021-12-14 10:15:57,309 INFO [main] 
o.e.j.s.h.C._nifi_content_viewer No Spring 
WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2021-12-14 10:15:57,314 INFO [main] 
o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started 
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@734a149a{nifi-content-viewer,/nifi-content- 
viewer,file:///home/user/nifi-1.15.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-content- 
viewer-1.15.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi- 
server-nar-1.15.0.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi- 
web-content-viewer-1.15.0.war}
2021-12-14 10:15:57,333 INFO [main] 
o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=5ms
2021-12-14 10:15:57,334 WARN [main] 
o.e.j.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor Duplicate mapping from / 
to default
2021-12-14 10:15:57,335 INFO [main] 
o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler._nifi_docs No Spring 
WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2021-12-14 10:15:57,370 INFO [main] 
o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started 
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6ce9771c{nifi-docs,/nifi- 
docs,file:///home/user/nifi-1.15.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs- 
1.15.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-server- 
nar-1.15.0.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web- 
docs-1.15.0.war}
2021-12-14 10:15:57,416 INFO [main] 
o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=33ms
2021-12-14 10:15:57,417 INFO [main] 
o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler._ No Spring 
WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2021-12-14 10:15:57,448 INFO [main] 
o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started 
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4a9b92c6{nifi- 
error,/,file:///home/user/nifi-1.15.0/work/jetty/nifi-web-error- 
1.15.0.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-server- 
nar-1.15.0.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web- 
error-1.15.0.war}
2021-12-14 10:15:57,652 INFO [main] 
o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started 
ServerConnector@38732372{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:8443}
2021-12-14 10:15:57,652 INFO [main] 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @24325ms
2021-12-14 10:15:57,682 INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.nar.NarAutoLoader Starting NAR Auto-Loader for 
directory ./extensions ...
2021-12-14 10:15:57,683 INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI 
is available at the following URLs:
2021-12-14 10:15:57,684 INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer 
https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi
2021-12-14 10:15:57,684 INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated 
communication with Bootstrap
2021-12-14 10:15:57,685 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi 
Controller initialization took 12136429891 nanoseconds ( 12  
seconds).
2021-12-14 10:16:14,358 INFO [pool-9-thread-1] 
o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of 
FlowFile Repository
2021-12-14 10:16:14,359 INFO [pool-9-thread-1] 
o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed 
FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с версии 1.14 по умолчанию запускается https сервер, с самоподписанными сертификатами, может дело в этом?

Comment: Изменил вопрос, обновил лог

Comment: ага, вот оно

2021-12-14 10:15:57,683 INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI 
is available at the following URLs:
2021-12-14 10:15:57,684 INFO [main] 
org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer 
https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi

Comment: Да,точно. В логах не увидел правильный адрес. Спасибо